# Type mismatch in lower bound types

Tags: scala

Given the following scala code:

```
trait A {}

class B[T <: A] {
    def f1(b: B[_ <: T]): Unit = {}
    def f2(b: B[_ <: T]): Unit = { b.f1(this) }
}
```

I get this compilation error:

> found   : B[T]
>
> required: B[_ <: _$2]
>
> Note: T >: _$2, but class B is invariant in type T.
>
> You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
>
> def f2(b: B[_ <: T]): Unit = { b.f1(this) }

It is not clear to me from the message how I can rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the parameter of `f1` and `f2` to be a `B[C]` for some `C <: T`, you should define it as such (for clarity's sake, at least), rather than with a `_`:

```
f1[C <: T](b: B[C]): Unit = {}
f2[C <: T](b: B[C]): Unit = ???
```

However, this poses a problem in your definition of `f2`, because then it becomes clear that `b.f1` must take a parameter of type `B[D]` for some `D <: C`, while `this` is of type `B[T]`, so it does not typecheck.

Why does it not typecheck? Because `B[T]` does not extend `B[D]` for some `D <: C`... unless you make `B` contravariant (as suggested in the compilation error).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a function that accepts an `Animal` also accepts a `Cat`, because a `Cat` is a type of `Animal`. However, this does not automatically apply to parameter types: An `Array[Cat]` is not a type of `Array[Animal]`, because you can't put a `Dog` into an `Array[Cat]`.

In your code, you try to call a function `f1` expecting a `B[_ <: C <: T]`, (where `C` is the `T` of the b passed into `f2`) but giving it a `B[T]`. This is only permitted if a `B[Animal]` is a type of `B[Cat]`--for example, if `B[T]` indicates that you can write type `T` to an array (an array that accepts `Animal` also accepts `Cat`), but the array might also hold other data types.

If you change `B[T <: A]` to `B[-T <: A]`, this marks `T` as a contravariant type, meaning that a `B[Animal]` is a `B[Cat]`, so functions expecting a `B[Cat]` will also accept a `B[Animal]`, and your code will compile.